# how can I add an icon/image for a child theme?

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I have set up a child theme of the twentyten theme.  In the themes section that under the appearance, I can only see the child theme's title, author name, and a grey box above it.  How can I add an icon/image to be displayed in the grey box?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Leave a file with the name `screenshot.png` inside the root of your child theme folder and it works.

> The recommended image size is 600x450. The screenshot will only be shown as 300x225, but the double-sized image allows for high-resolution viewing on HiDPI displays.

- see on [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Screenshot)

Comment: Note: aim for an image resolution of 600x450px, if you want to take advantage of the HiDPI ("Retina") display used in the WP-Admin.

Answer (score 0):

As @bueltge suggested simply create a `screenshot.png` in your child theme folder.

You can get more information from the [WordPress Codex here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Screenshot).

Comment: Sorry, but what is the purpose of ths answer? you haven't added anything to the original answer.